# How to add the sound effect of a ball rolling, based on his velocity?

Tags: unity, audio, sound-effects

I have a ball which roll (like all ball does :) ) ...

My ball can roll on different type of surfaces (2 or 3) and at different velocity.

I don't know how to approach to reproduce in my game the sound effect.

I can assume to do :

1. Get an Sfx of a rolling ball
2. Run in loop if my ball is moving

then ?

Well.. i need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved.

If I move up/down the audio.Pitch based on rigidbody.velocity.magnitude, i obtain what i was looking for

Example:

_audio.pitch = rb.velocity.magnitude / AudioSpeedAdjuster;